# Jfrog CLI for Artifactory: download folder archive

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am using JFrog CLI ([`jfrog rt download`](http://ttps://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles)) to download build reports from Artifactory that are published there by GitLab CI in **unpacked** state in order to allow unhindered html reports browsing.
However it takes extremely long (10-20 minutes) because of just how many small files there are.

I see that Artifactory has [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveFolderorRepositoryArchive) to download whole repository folder content in one swoop as a single archive.
But I am not able to find any way to do the same using JFrog CLI.

Am I missing something or is there truly no way to download whole folder content as an archive using JFrog CLI?

P.S.: I am aware that there is a configuration option on Artifactory that supposedly allows to browse contents of archives, but there are reasons (organizational and technical) preventing me from using it

Answer (score 0):

Using the CLI you can increase the "--threads" value. I have seen a massive improvement when downloading a directory with lots of small files when increasing the number of threads.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. However, after a while the download started to fail with `Unexpected EOF` errors leaving a couple random files undownloaded. With whole thing running as a part of a bigger automated process inside a Docker container, the only immediate solution is to retry and then observe the process failing to download some other small file.